# Relative paths in XSL include when called from a JAR

Tags: java

I have an issue that works something like this:

- I have a JAR file in one location that creates HTML using XSL and style sheets.
- The XSL and style sheets are located in another folder.
- The style sheets have a relative include on them.

My understanding after reading around online, I call the base XSL document, and then everything else should be relative to that base XSL document.

E.g.<xsl:include href="./TransmissionData.xsl"/>

But it cannot find that file. Am I missing something? I'll include any other information required if you need more details.

Comment: Did you try using a full path? I am convinced your problem is not related to what you think.

Comment: When we use the full qualified path, yes it seems to work (although we have not tested exhaustively). It also works when being run from eclipse (without changes, with the relative path).

Comment: You have a "path" issue. Can you post the code? When run from IDE, the "." is resolved to be the current project's location. That doesn't work when you run a built application. Also, those details you just mentioned are relevant to the question you are asking. They should be part of the details of your problem description along with minimal, reproducible code.

Comment: One thing you can try is the reference without the dot. Just `<xsl:include href="TransmissionData.xsl"/>`.

Comment: I managed to find the issue - its not related to the code, but could probably be fixed with a URI resolver. Its considering the base path the location the jar is being run from (e.g. not the location of the JAR or the location of the XSL documents). I'll probably just post a simple answer or close this. Did not seem to be any information on StackOverflow for my specific type of issue.

Comment: Yes, please do. Post the answer to your question. Then wait two days to accept your own answer.

Comment: "_Its considering the base path the location the jar is being run from (e.g. not the location of the JAR or the location of the XSL documents)._" - This is what I suspected when I wrote "_You have a "path" issue.... the "." is resolved to be the current project's location. _"

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being fairly simple: the "base path" is set the the path where the command line is being called from.

In my case, we had a statement similar to this...

java -jar /location/of/jar/project.jar

With XSL/CSS in the location of /location/of/jar/xsl

When run, the project was using the location that the command line was called from. Updated references to include the path were successful, or calling it from the jars location instead.